# Verbal Reasoning (Puzzle)

Tags: puzzle

There are four persons A, B, C and D. The total amount of money with A and B together is equal to the total amount of money with C and D together. But the total amount of money with B and D together is more than the amount of money with A and C together. The amount of money with A is more than that B. Who has the least amount of money?

I tried to solve this question, not once but many times and also searched on the internet. It is question from a verbal reasoning (puzzle test)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $A+B=C+D\cdots\cdots(1)\\B+D>A+C\cdots\cdots(2)\\A>B\cdots\cdots(3)$

From $(3)$ we get that $D>C.$

Adding $B$  on both sides of $(1)$.

$A+2B=C+D+B.\\or,\,A+2B-C=B+D>A+C.\space \space [\text {Using (2)}]\\or,\,A+2B-C>A+C.\\or,\,2B>2C.\\or,\,B>C.$

So $C$ has the least amount of money.

If $ A>D$ ,

$A+B=C+D\\\implies A+B-C=D\\\implies A+B-C<A\\\implies B-C<0\\\implies B<C. $

Comment: Is it possible that B have the least amount of money? Because in my book the correct answer is 'B'. But your explanation seems more valid.

Comment: Using equations (1) and (2) we can also get A<D.  If, however A>D then B<C .

Comment: Can you please solve it? I tried to solve it.

Comment: ok. I will post it after sometime. But I don't really see the point in assuming A>D when the calculations are showing A<D.

Answer (score 0):

$A+C=C+D$ implies $A=D$. Then $A+B=D+B>A+C$ implies $B>C$. As we are also given that $A>B$, we fined
$$D=A>B>C$$
and $C$ is the poorest.

Answer (score 0):

From the given conditions:
$$ A + C = C + D \Rightarrow A = D$$
$$ B + D > A + C \Rightarrow B + A > C + A \Rightarrow B > C$$
$$ A > B $$
So we have,
$$ A = D > B > C  $$